# Sync local Sqlite data with kinesis stream

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am developing an android app which stores data in sqlite DB it will be updating the Kinesis stream but, when there is no network I am not able to manage the older data to go into kinesis.

I wanted to know is there any way to sync the sqlite DB with kinesis stream which syncs my data once i have the internet connection ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to be using the AWSKinesesRecorder:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-kinesis.html

Also, to take account for the internet connection, I recommend that you programmatically listen for the internet connection:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html